# python user input to the function

Tags: python, function, input, keras, prediction

i have 2 functions which one of them loading and preparing the data to the test

and the other one performing the test , which is reading the file as a test and generate

the second file as a test result

what i want to do is user input something instead of the file and then perform the test

first function:

```
def load_test_data(source, X_word_to_ix, max_len):
    f = open(source, 'r')
    X_data = f.read()
    f.close()
    X = [text_to_word_sequence(x)[::-1] for x in X_data.split('\n') if 0 < len(x) <= max_len]
    for i, sentence in enumerate(X):
        for j, word in enumerate(sentence):
            if word in X_word_to_ix:
                X[i][j] = X_word_to_ix[word]
            elif word in X_word_to_ix is None:
                X[i][j] = None
            else:
                X[i][j] = X_word_to_ix['UNK']
    return X
```

instead the source there should be a user input

second function:

```
if len(saved_weights) == 0:
    print("The network hasn't been trained! Program will exit...")
    sys.exit()
else:
    X_test = load_test_data('test.txt', X_word_to_ix, MAX_LEN)
    X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=X_max_len, dtype='int32')
    model.load_weights(saved_weights)

    predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test), axis=2)
    sequences = []
    for prediction in predictions:
        sequence = ' '.join([y_ix_to_word[index] for index in prediction if index > 0])
        print(sequence)
        sequences.append(sequence)
    np.savetxt('test_result', sequences, fmt='%s')
```

now its clear i want user input instead reading the file as an input and generate a file as an output

i want get input from user and give and output not to the file

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: thanks for replying both function working with file instead of the source i want user input and instead save the result in file i just want to see as a normal print? is that clear

Comment: I think so. Do you know how to get input from the user?

Comment: yes somehow i managed but only i get an error which i do not know hot to fix i am still investigating

Comment: You should edit your post if it’s still the same question, or create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but as per my understanding you want to take inputs from the terminal(user) as a file name or anything you want to input you can use system arguments For that do this:

```
import sys
filename=sys.argv[0]
print("arguments I want to pass:", filename)
```

You can add more number of arguments by changing number in argv like sys.argv[1]. While running the file use:

```
python file.py arg1, arg2
```

Comment: well i want take the input from the user instead of reading the file

Comment: You can use this for taking the inputs from user too just add what input you want to give as arguments while executing python file.py arguments

Comment: sorry for that but i just want both function works while taking input from user not reading the file

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear and also include your desire output. Use tkinter for dialog pop up for user input. Pass the argument to second function.

Use class since you have multiple function. As per my understanding you want the first function to read the file is that correct? Hence, you should use a dialogbox for a user to insert an input by using tkinter or just a simple user input request, you can use `input('Please insert: ')`

You can pass the input to your function.

Comment: sorry for that but i just want both function works while taking input from user not reading the file